# a trig question

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

Because my book doesn't have solutions to these problems, I'm checking here if I solved them correctly (I know it's all probably wrong):

1) $$\tan(\pi+\frac{x}{3})>0$$
What I noticed first is that I could convert tangens to $\frac{\sin}{\cos}$, then remove $\pi$ from both so I finished with: $$tan(\frac{x}{3})>0$$ $$x>3\pi+n\pi, \space n\in \Bbb Z$$ I'm now not quite sure how to interpret this. What I think the best thing to do here is to consider this as interval:$(3\pi+n\pi, +\infty)$, and since the border of $tgx>0$ is $\frac{3\pi}{2}$, the $+\infty$should be replaced by it. And that should be the solution.

2) $$2 \cos(\pi-2x)>1$$
-removing $\pi$ $$\cos(2x)<-\frac{1}{2}$$
It's obvious now that the condition is $\frac{2\pi}{3}<2x<\frac{4\pi}{3}$, if I divide the whole "condition" by 2, I get the interval of the solution:$\frac{\pi}{3}<x<\frac{2\pi}{3}$. (?) 
I don't know how to use this mechanism in the other problems since then I get different results.

3) $$\cot(\frac{3\pi}{2}-\frac{x}{2})\le\sqrt{3}$$
$$\frac{3\pi}{2}-\frac{x}{2}\le\frac{\pi}{6}+n\pi$$
$$x\geq\frac{2\pi}{3}-2n\pi$$
... I don't know. This is a dead end.

Comment: you can also use \tan and \cos

Comment: What's the difference? It's harder for me since I have to type in one more \ which is right Alt and Q, really unconfortable.

Comment: I said you can, I never said you have to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the tangent ratio is positive in the first & in the third quadrant.

$$\tan\frac x3>0\implies n\pi<\frac x3<n\pi+\frac\pi2$$ where $n$ is any integer

For the last,
$$\cot\left(3\cdot\frac\pi2-\frac x2\right)=\cot\left(\pi+\frac\pi2-\frac x2\right)=\cot\left(\frac\pi2-\frac x2\right)=\tan\frac x2$$

So, we need $\displaystyle\tan\frac x2\le\sqrt3=\tan\frac\pi3$

Now, $\displaystyle\tan\frac x2>\sqrt3$ if $\displaystyle m\pi+\frac\pi3<\frac x2\le m\pi+\frac\pi2$  where $m$ is any integer

We need $U-\{m\pi+\frac\pi3<\frac x2\le m\pi+\frac\pi2\}$ where $U$ is teh Universal Set

Comment: How did you get this?

Comment: @user151802 Which part do you not understand?

Comment: @user151802, tangent ratio is positive in the first & in the third quadrant.

Comment: First, how did you get the "<npi+ pi/2?

Comment: @user151802, Do you know about the period of tangent function is $\pi$

Comment: Yes, I was confused since I always draw the "unit circle" and you go from right to left, from smaller to bigger, that's why I was confused by the npi<npi + pi/2 (because I usually get it the other way >). Thank you for clearing things up, so basically, I just use the condition until I get x alone. In the third problem I got the solution: [pi+2npi<x<8pi/3+2np].